# Read a file in R with mixed character encodings

Tags: html, r, character-encoding

I'm trying to read tables into R from HTML pages that are mostly encoded in UTF-8 (and declare `<meta charset="utf-8">`) but have some strings in some other encodings (I think Windows-1252 or ISO 8859-1). [Here's an example.](http://web.archive.org/web/20190603144739id_/http://api-ak.wunderground.com/weatherstation/ListStations.asp?selectedCountry=fr) I want everything decoded properly into an R data frame. `XML::readHTMLTable` takes an `encoding` argument but doesn't seem to allow one to try multiple encodings.

So, in R, how can I try several encodings for each line of the input file? In Python 3, I'd do something like:

```py
with open('file', 'rb') as o:
    for line in o:
        try:
            line = line.decode('UTF-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            line = line.decode('Windows-1252')
```

Comment: This question is currently being discussed on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385841/why-was-my-answer-to-my-own-question-deleted?cb=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There do seem to be R library functions for guessing character encodings, like `stringi::stri_enc_detect`, but when possible, it's probably better to use the simpler determinstic method of trying a fixed set of encodings in order. It looks like the best way to do this is to take advantage of the fact that when `iconv` fails to convert a string, it returns `NA`.

```
linewise.decode = function(path)
    sapply(readLines(path), USE.NAMES = F, function(line) {
        if (validUTF8(line))
            return(line)
        l2 = iconv(line, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8")
        if (!is.na(l2))
            return(l2)
        l2 = iconv(line, "Shift-JIS", "UTF-8")
        if (!is.na(l2))
            return(l2)
        stop("Encoding not detected")
    })
```

If you create a test file with

```sh
$ python3 -c 'with open("inptest", "wb") as o: o.write(b"This line is ASCII\n" + "This line is UTF-8: I like π\n".encode("UTF-8") + "This line is Windows-1252: Müller\n".encode("Windows-1252") + "This line is Shift-JIS: ハローワールド\n".encode("Shift-JIS"))'
```

then `linewise.decode("inptest")` indeed returns

```
[1] "This line is ASCII"                    
[2] "This line is UTF-8: I like π"          
[3] "This line is Windows-1252: Müller"     
[4] "This line is Shift-JIS: ハローワールド"
```

To use `linewise.decode` with `XML::readHTMLTable`, just say something like `XML::readHTMLTable(linewise.decode("http://example.com"))`.

Comment: doesn´t it have to be the other way around `iconv(lines,  from = "UTF-8", to = "Windows-1252")` ?

Comment: @BigDataScientist No, I want everything to ultimately be in UTF-8 (since it turns out that R doesn't have a binary-representation-free string type like Python 3's `str`), and Windows-1252 is the preexisting encoding of some of the lines I want to change.